# VS 2015 asks for property name when nesting sass with &:nth-child(2)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sass, nested

i'm having problem in VS 2015 when trying to nest a class in sass. I'm using gulp to compile the sass files. When i try to nest a class with "&.class" VS is underlining the "&" sign in green and on hover displays the following error:

Missing a property name before the colon (':') in the "(property) : (value)" declaration.

that's the piece of code:

```
.class {
    //css rule 

    &:nth-child(2) {
        //css rule
          }
}
```

Comment: Does your file end with the .scss extension?

Comment: Do you have any VS extensions installed that could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

After VS and gulp function restart the problem was solved, thanks.